# Performing an asynchronous transformation within a Kafka Stream

Tags: concurrency, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Assume I have two Kafka topics, *A* and *B*. I am trying to develop a system that pulls records from *A*, applies a transformation to each record, then publishes the transformed records to *B*. In this case, the transformation involves calling a REST endpoint over HTTP.

Being relatively new to Kafka, I was glad to see that the Kafka Streams project already solved this type of problem (consume-transform-publish). Unfortunately, I discovered that transformations in Kafka streams are *blocking* operations. Instinctively, I try to call HTTP endpoints in a *non-blocking*, asynchronous manner.

Does this mean that Kafka Streams will not work in this situation? Does this mean that I must revert back to calling the REST endpoint in a blocking manner? Is this even an acceptable pattern for Kafka Streams? Stream-based data processing is still relatively new to me, so I am not entirely familiar with its concurrency models.

Comment: Would be good to know a bit more what exactly you intend to do with the calls. Mind posting the (pseudo)code to build the Kafka Streams instance you are using? I ask because calling a REST endpoint doesn't sound like a typical transformation. The latter often implies changing keys and values.

Comment: Adam, have you explored actual asynchronous methods for this issue? Having looked at it more, I think my answer could have been incomplete or wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: after looking in to this further, I am not sure that this is the right answer...

---

I am new to Kafka and Kafka Streams (hereafter referred to as "Kafka"), but having encountered and considered similar questions, here is my perspective:

Kafka has two salient features:

1. All parallelism is achieved through the partitioning of topics
2. Within a partition of a topic, processing is strongly ordered, one-at-a-time.

Many really nice properties fall out from these features. For example, [stream-based "transactions"](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/event-streams-kafka), I think, is one of the coolest.

But whether these properties are actually "features" in the sense that you want them, of course, depends on the application. If you don't want strongly ordered processing with parallelism based on topic partitioning, then you might not want to be using Kafka for that application.

So, with regard to:

> Does this mean that Kafka Streams will not work in this situation?

It will work, but increased parallelism is achieved through increased partitioning.

> Does this mean that I must revert back to calling the REST endpoint in a blocking manner?

Yes, I think it does—but I'm not sure why that would be a "reversion". Personally, that's what I like about Kafka: blocking code is simpler. If I want more parallelism, I can run more threads. There's no shared state, after all.

Comment: By the way, I don't think there's anything special about making an HTTP request here. You could replace "HTTP request" with "accessing remote state" of any kind. Could be a remote database, right? Either way, the access has to be synchronous because your stream processing functions run top-down one time per message.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, the relevant configuration can be found here: http://docs.confluent.io/2.1.0-alpha1/streams/developer-guide.html#required-configuration-parameters: `num.stream.threads: The number of threads to execute stream processing`; so if you want to process many partitions using one machine, you can just up the thread count to match your partition count.

Comment: Then again, I don't think you even need to increase thread-count. Kafka assigns partitions to tasks and I think one thread can just handle all the partitions (http://docs.confluent.io/2.1.0-alpha1/streams/architecture.html#parallelism-model).

Comment: Just jumping in to highlight that the latest docs for this are available at http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/streams/developer-guide.html#required-configuration-parameters.  The `/2.1.0-alpha1/` links were for the Kafka Streams Tech Preview, which is deprecated now that Apache Kafka 0.10.0.0 (which includes the first release of Kafka Streams) is officially available.